# How to open a .glb or .gltf file in blender?

Tags: import, gltf

My question is about opening .glb or .gltf files in Blender. I don't see these extensions in the *Import* options, although *Export* allows me to create files with either of those extensions.

Comment: an importer could be not yet available, but you could perhaps use this tool to read and convert to importable files https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Asset_Import_Library

Comment: Hope someone updates this when an import is available...

Comment: glTF 2.0 import and export are shipping with Blender 2.80 Beta.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Blender comes with [glTF-Blender-IO](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO) pre-installed since 2.80.

This is a refactoring of the original Khronos glTF exporter, combined with @Julien's importer.  Both of the original projects should be considered obsolete in favor of the newer, combined glTF-Blender-IO project.

The Blender Manual includes [documentation on ways to use glTF](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/import_export/scene_gltf2.html).

Answer (score 13):

GLTF Importer for Blender - now in progress:

https://github.com/ksons/gltf-blender-importer

Answer (score 7):

A more advanced glTF importer for Blender : https://github.com/julienduroure/gltf2-blender-importer

Comment: Awesome, I had an FBX with embedded textures, but when I imported it to Blender 2.79 the textures were discarded. I was able to open the FBX in Windows 3D Paint and there textures were their. Windows 3D Paint can save to GLB. With this importer addon, I was able to get the textures.

Answer (score 6):

In short, there's an [exporter for the GLTF format](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter) from Blender (which I assume you have installed), but as of this moment, no one has written an importer add-on or extended the export add-on to support importing as well. This is why you can export, but have no options for importing.

Comment: Updated importer/exporter https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO
Currently supported